# Internet Explorer 11 issue with SPServices

Tags: jquery, spservices, internet-explorer

I have created js file which have spservices common function which I am using in my page. Below is the code for one of the function which will use for Add/Delete/Update by sending appropriate parameters to the function

```
function itemOperation(webUrl, listName, operationType, dataArray, id) {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: webUrl,
    listName: listName,
    ID: id,
    batchCmd: operationType, //New, Update, Delete
    valuepairs: dataArray, //[["Title","TestItOut"]]
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      console.log(Status);
    }
  });
}
```

I am also using datatables plugin with spservices. Now what I find is line which ever comes after above function call is not getting execute. That is just happening in IE-11 but it works very good in chrome and FireFox.

Other funny thing what I found is if I open IE developer console and work than it works as expected, may be it work cause when I open console, IE emulate is set to IE 8 by default.

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem may be the console.log() line. With IE, (I believe) console is only available when the debugger is opened, thus an error is thrown if it is not.

Replace console.log(Status) with alert(Status) and you hopefully will see it.

Comment: That's really strange. Kind of issue

Comment: Did my suggestion address the issue?

Comment: console.log() isn't a good debugging technique in IE.

Comment: Yes @PaulT. It works :)

Comment: Hi Millind im having the same exact issue you are having,Did you manage to solve it.Its all good in Chrome,Firefox but on IE it doesnt work and im using SPServices.
If you have the fix please let me know

Comment: This is defininitely my "WTF" of the day. Just spent 4 hrs trying to work out why SPServices would not run.